# реализовать запрос sql без UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно реализовать запрос **БЕЗ** `UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS`!

База данных HR содержит информацию об отделах, а также их расположении, даже если в этих отделах еще не числится ни один сотрудник. Аналогично представлена информация о потенциально возможном расположении отделов, которые могут быть созданы в будущем. То есть существуют такие адреса, по которым не расположен ни один отдел. Необходимо сделать выборку, которая показала бы все возможные адреса, зарезервированные предприятием, затем необходимо вывести количество отделов, которое числятся по соответствующему адресу и количество человек, которые работают по этому адресу. Запрос не должен содержать таких операторов, как UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS.

Если кому интересно, вот один из моих вариантов

```
select HR.Locations.Location_id,Count (HR.Departments.department_id)
from HR.Locations Left join HR.Departments
group by HR.Locations.location_id;
```

не знаю, как добавить еще `Count(HR.Employees.employee_id)`, не используя `Union` и т. п.

Comment: Необходимо - сделайте. Или предлагаете за вас явное тестовое задание сделать?

Comment: я прошу помощи, если вы не в силах её предоставить, не нужно отвечать

Comment: Помощь предполагает наличие чего-то, сделанного вами. Пока что его нет и это работа за вас. А если вы не в силах прочитать местную справку - может и спрашивать не стоит?

Comment: конечно, сейчас добавлю кучу нерабочего кода к вопросу. Если у кого есть идея - пусть её подкинут

Comment: Мне например так по голому тексту сложно и влом делать запрос. И на чем я его проверять буду ? Создайте тестовую базу на sqlfiddle.com, напишите запрос пусть с union который выбирает именно то что вам надо. А я его тогда как нибудь трансформирую

Comment: Структуры базы данных бы привели, если есть. Таблички какие:  адреса, предприятия, отделы?

Comment: А свой count(emploes)  вам никто не мешает прямо в списке выборки основного запроса написать подзапросом. т.е. `select HR.Locations.Location_id,...., (select count(1) from emp where emp.id=HRxxx) from HR.Locations,...`

Comment: подзапрос должен вернуть одно значение, а в моем случае для каждого location должно быть свое значение count (employees)

Comment: @JuliaPominchuk, то, что вы написали ваш запрос -- хорошо. Но отсутствие схем БД мешает ответить на ваш вопрос, поэтому все ставят ему минусы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После углубления в структуру все оказалось проще, чем казалось изначально. Переклеиваем сразу к расположениям и департаменты и людей там работающих. Количество уникальных ID-департамента - это и есть количество департаментов в данном месте, а количество человек - количество их ID.

```
select L.Loc_id,
       count(distinct D.dep_id) as dep_count,
       count(E.Emp_Id) as emp_count
  from Locations L
  left join Departments D on L.loc_Id=D.loc_id
  left join Employees E on E.dep_id=D.dep_id
 group by L.loc_id;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и делала, единственное, что нужно было указать дистинкт. Именно это и нужно было.